# Servlet for querying database on some high-loaded system

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

**What should the code do:** Process client HTML requests, query database and return the answer in XML. Working with a high load.
I need to know how can it be optimized.
Is something terribly wrong with this code?

**Input data:** HTML-session, MAC-address (in form of GET argument).

**Output data:** XML (`session_id`, `session_sign`).

**Servlet:**

```
package com.packageexample.servlet;

import java.io.IOException; 

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource;
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolProperties;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class TestServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/Servlet")
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3954448641206344959L;
    private static final long SESSION_TIMEOUT = 360000;
    private static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final String JDBC_MYSQL_SERVER = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.100:3306/test?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8";
    private static final String JDBC_MYSQL_USER = "test";
    private static final String JDBC_MYSQL_PASSWORD = "test";

    private static DataSource datasource;
    private static enum RESPONSE_STATUS {SESSION_NEW, SESSION_RESTORED, SESSION_OK, MAC_UNDEFINED, UNAUTHORIZED_ACCESS, HACK_ATTEMPT};
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Servlet() {
        super();
        PoolProperties p = new PoolProperties();
        p.setUrl(JDBC_MYSQL_SERVER);
        p.setDriverClassName(JDBC_DRIVER);
        p.setUsername(JDBC_MYSQL_USER);
        p.setPassword(JDBC_MYSQL_PASSWORD);
        p.setJmxEnabled(true);
        p.setTestWhileIdle(false);
        p.setTestOnBorrow(true);
        p.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
        p.setTestOnReturn(false);
        p.setValidationInterval(30000);
        p.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(30000);
        p.setMaxActive(100);
        p.setInitialSize(10);
        p.setMaxWait(10000);
        p.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(60);
        p.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(30000);
        p.setMinIdle(10);
        p.setLogAbandoned(true);
        p.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
        p.setJdbcInterceptors(
                "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;"
                        + "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer");
        /*Using apache tomcat7 datasource for connection pooling
        /We choose to use DBCP, because we have a high load on our project*/
        datasource = new DataSource();
        datasource.setPoolProperties(p);
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //Need to check if we've got session already
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        String session_id = null;
        //Parse GET parameter mac from client request
        String mac = request.getParameter("mac");

        if (session!=null) {session_id = session.getId();}

        //Firstly, we need to check whether we got some MAC-address provided at all 
        if (mac == null) {
            makeXml (request,response,session_id, RESPONSE_STATUS.MAC_UNDEFINED);
            return;
        }
        //Now that we need to deal with db, 
        ManageDatabase dbDo = new ManageDatabase();
        /*Check that there's a record for this MAC in database
        /If yes, return this device*/
        Device device = dbDo.getDeviceByMAC (mac, datasource);

        if (device==null) {
            makeXml (request,response,session_id, RESPONSE_STATUS.UNAUTHORIZED_ACCESS);
            return;
        }
        /*Now that we know for sure that we've got some valid mac-address provided, 
        /we need to check, if client has got some SESSION_ID*/
        if (session_id == null) { 
            session = request.getSession();
            device.setSessionId(session.getId());
            dbDo.setSessionId(device, datasource);
            makeXml (request,response,device.getSessionId(), RESPONSE_STATUS.SESSION_NEW);
            return;
        }
        else {
            //If session_id is not null, we need to check if it is valid for mac provided
            if (!(device.getSessionId().equals(session.getId()))) {
                makeXml (request,response,session_id, RESPONSE_STATUS.HACK_ATTEMPT);
                return;
            }
            //If session_id not null and it's a valid session, then check it for timeout. Restore if needed
            long sessionActiveTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - session.getLastAccessedTime();
            if (sessionActiveTime > SESSION_TIMEOUT) {
                makeXml (request,response,session_id, RESPONSE_STATUS.SESSION_RESTORED);
            }
            else{
                makeXml (request,response,session_id, RESPONSE_STATUS.SESSION_OK);
            }
        }       

    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    }
    protected void makeXml (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String sid, Enum<?> res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.setAttribute("session_id", sid);
        request.setAttribute("session_sign", res);
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("Result.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

**ManageDatabase:**

```
package com.packageexample.servlet;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource;

class ManageDatabase {
    private static final String MYSQL_QUERY_CHECK_MAC = "SELECT * FROM device WHERE mac=?;";
    private static final String MYSQL_QUERY_UPDATE_SESSION_ID = "UPDATE device set session_id=? WHERE mac=?;";

    Device getDeviceByMAC(String mac, DataSource datasource) {
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Device device = null;
        try (Connection connection = datasource.getConnection();    
                PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(MYSQL_QUERY_CHECK_MAC, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);){

            statement.setString(1, mac);
            rs = statement.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                device = new Device();
                device.setMac(rs.getString("mac"));
                device.setSessionId(rs.getString("session_id"));                
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e){System.out.println(e);}
        finally { 
            if (rs!=null) 
                try {rs.close();} 
            catch (SQLException e) {System.out.println(e);}
        }
        return device;
    }


    void setSessionId(Device device, DataSource datasource) {
        try (Connection connection = datasource.getConnection();    
                PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(MYSQL_QUERY_UPDATE_SESSION_ID, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);) {
            statement.setString(1, device.getSessionId());
            statement.setString(2, device.getMac());
            statement.executeUpdate();
        }
        catch (SQLException e){System.out.println(e);}
    }
}
```

**Device:**

```
package com.packageexample.servlet;

class Device {
    private String mac;
    private String sessionId;
    public String getMac() {
        return mac;
    }
    public void setMac(String mac_address) {
        this.mac = mac_address;
    }
    public String getSessionId() {
        return sessionId;
    }
    public void setSessionId(String session_id) {
        this.sessionId = session_id;
    }
    public String toString () {
        return "Device mac:" + this.mac +" ; session_id:" + this.sessionId;
    }

}
```

**Result.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/xml; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<result>
<session_id>
<% 
out.println(request.getAttribute("session_id"));
%>
</session_id>
<session_sign>
<% 
out.println(request.getAttribute("session_sign"));
%> 
</session_sign>
</result>
```

Comment: Ensure that you have indexes defined on the `device` table for the `session_id` and `mac` columns.

Answer (score 5):

Some minor random notes:

1. Instead of commenting, like this:

   ```
       //If session_id is not null, we need to check if it is valid for mac provided
       if (!(device.getSessionId().equals(session.getId()))) {
           makeXml (request,response,session_id, RESPONSE_STATUS.HACK_ATTEMPT);
           return;
       }
   ```

   I'd use an explaining variable:

   ```
   final boolean isValidMac = device.getSessionId().equals(session.getId());
   if (!isValidMac) {
       makeXml (request, response, session_id, RESPONSE_STATUS.HACK_ATTEMPT);
       return;
   }
   ```

   This would make the comment unnecessary. References:

   *Chapter 6. Composing Methods*, *Introduce Explaining Variable* in *Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code* by Martin Fowler:

   > Put the result of the expression, or parts of the expression, 
   >   in a temporary variable with a name that explains the purpose.

   And *Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*, *G19: Use Explanatory Variables*.
2. I'd rename `SESSION_TIMEOUT` to `SESSION_TIMEOUT_MILLIS`. It would help readers, maintainers.
3. JDBC connection details often change. A configuration file be better for them.
4. `session_id` and `mac_address` do not follow the `camelCase` convention which the other parts of the code use.
5. Comments like this are unnecessary:

   ```
    /**
    * Servlet implementation class TestServlet
    */
   ```

   It says nothing more than the code already does, it's rather noise. (*Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*: *Chapter 4: Comments, Noise Comments*)
6. Instead of raw strings I'd consider using this:

   ```
   ConnectionState.class.getCanonicalName() + ";" + 
       StatementFinalizer.class.getCanonicalName()
   ```

   It's not a big difference but a little bit less error-prone.
7. The `else` keyword is unnecessary here:

   ```
   /*Now that we know for sure that we've got some valid mac-address provided, 
   /we need to check, if client has got some SESSION_ID*/
   if (session_id == null) { 
       ...
       return;
   }
   else {
       ... // content of the else block
   }
   ```

   It could be simply the following:

   ```
   if (session_id == null) { 
       ...
       return;
   }
   ... // content of the (former) else block
   ```

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't make much sense to have a connection pool to be used by just one servlet.  Usually, the connection pool is shared by the entire webapp.  Furthermore, much of the setup can be accomplished by [configuration](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html) rather than with code.  It is certainly bad practice to hard-code connection strings, especially passwords, in your code.  You wouldn't want to have to recompile the application to point to a testing database or change the password.  You also wouldn't want to store the code with the password in a source code control system.

Comment: Agreed on hard-coded connection strings, we ought to know better since last century.